# pandas: How to sort values in order of most repeated to least repeated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Suppose a `df` as:

```
   A   B  ...
   2   .
   3   .
   2   .
   3   
   2   
   1
```

I expect output to be:

```
   A   B  ...
   2   .
   2   .
   2   .   
   3   
   3   
   1
```

Because 2 was repeated the most, then 3 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a sorting function which maps the counts of the sort-by column to `sort_values` as key:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1], 'B': range(6)})
df = df.sort_values(by='A', key=lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()), ascending=False)
```

This transforms a dataframe that looks like:

```
   A  B
0  2  0
1  3  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  2  4
5  1  5
```

into

```
   A  B
0  2  0
2  2  2
4  2  4
1  3  1
3  3  3
5  1  5
```

Answer (score 1):

First add a new column counting the repetitions:

```
>>> df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('count')
```

Then sort by this new column:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['C','A'], ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
df['Frequency'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('count')
df.sort_values('Frequency', inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, as I posted I myself come to same solution

Answer (score 1):

Try `value_counts` and `argsort`

```
out = df.iloc[(-df.A.value_counts().reindex(df.A)).argsort()]
Out[647]: 
   A     B  ...
0  2     .  NaN
2  2     .  NaN
4  2  None  NaN
1  3     .  NaN
3  3  None  NaN
5  1  None  NaN
```